# Setting environment variable for docker container at runtime

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, centos, dockerfile

I have a requirement to set the environment variable for docker container at runtime. The value can only be determined at runtime by combination two other variables which are available at runtime. In a simpler form, the following is not working.

```
docker run -ti -e host="name" -e port="123" centos:7 bash -c "export url=$host:$port; env"
```

returns the following where url is empty when the value of $host and $port is available to construct $url ?

```sh
...
host=name
url=:
port=123
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to single quote the shell command to avoid your interactive shell expanding the variable before the docker shell sees them:

```
docker run -ti -e host="name" -e port="123" centos:7 bash -c 'export url=$host:$port; env'
```

With single quotes, your shell will pass `export url=$host:$port; env` to Docker.

With double quotes, your current shell will first dutifully expand the variables, and therefore just pass `url=:; env`

Comment: this works. I thought my question had an example of simplified form of problem that I am facing. Actually, I have a dockerfile with a custom entrypoint. This environment variable $host should be available in container. I can confirm from the logs that the $url is set during the start up of container. But when I bash into the container, this variable is empty.