# How to update environment variable for different value for each different users in docker container for container is runnig

Tags: linux, docker-compose, environment-variables, docker-container

First of all, if I need to talk about the situation I want to do, I have docker containers that I set up with the `docker-compose.yml` file. Inside this docker image, there are 2 more users ("user1" and "user2"), one of which is the "root" user. (I created them in `Dockerfile`, everything is fine so far). There is one enviroment variable defined for these users. (echo $env_val). I want this variable to have a separate value for each user and I want to manage this value dynamically. In other words, I want to manage the "environment" variable used in "docker-compose.yml" on a user basis.

```
version: '3'
services:
   app1:
      image: image1
      enviromnet:
         - env_val=34052    # this value default 34034 but for user1 value is assing 34052
      entrypoint: /bin/sh/ start_container.sh

   app2:
      image: image1
      enviromnet:
         - env_val=34028    # this value default 34028 but for user2 value is assing 34028
      entrypoint: /bin/sh/ start_container.sh
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file is like this. The `env_val` variable here is assigned the value I specified only for the root user. But I want the value I gave to be assigned only for the user I selected in the image. I didn't see any solution for this. Do you have any advice for me to meet this need?

Note: I tried these solution

- I was able to assign the value I wanted to this enviroment with a script I wrote, but then when I logged into this container with `docker exec -it container_name bash` and logged in with the user I chose `su - user1`, I could not see the value I assigned. Default value was set.
  My command: `docker exec -u 0 container_name /bin/bash -c "su - user1; source ~/.bash_profile; export env_val=34052"`
- [Setting environment variable for docker container at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688914/setting-environment-variable-for-docker-container-at-runtime)
- This solution decides on the relevant environemt during the image creation phase. In my case, I want to change the value of this variable when the image files are created, while running the image.
  [Docker different environment variables for the same service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64245853/docker-different-environment-variables-for-the-same-service)

thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's not a solution that suits me, I found a way. I wrote a new script. This script takes the value of the environmet variable that I will change as a parameter. I'm sending this command to the docker container standing on the host machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

docker exec -u 0 container_name /bin/bash -c "echo export env_val=$1 >> /home/user1/.bash_profile; su - user1; source ~/.bash_profile; <run_another_command>"
```

This command appends the command I need to the end of the .bash_profile of the user I want inside the running container. It also logs in with the user I want and sources the .bash_profile file. Afterwards, I can start the application that I will run in the configuration I want.

Thus, when I log in with this user, the configuration I want is done. Finally, when I stop or delete the container, my image is not affected by this change.